# Creating a pivot table with identical values used as columns

Tags: sql-server-2008, pivot, sql-server-express

I have a table that I need to pivot out using SQL Management Studio. This particular example lives on a SQLExpress server, but I have similar tables on a 2008 r2 server that I will also be applying this to.

This table contains the results of a survey (50+ questions and a few hundred GuestID's). Fairly straight forward to pivot, however I've hit a snag in the way that multiple choice questions and answers were entered into the table.

My table looks like this:

```
GuestID      Question                              Answer
1            How old are you?                      30
1            Do you own a car?                     Yes
1            Why do you own a car?                 Convenience
1            Why do you own a car?                 To get the girl
1            Why do you own a car?                 So I can go through the drive-thru
```

I want to pivot to this (... to keep it short):

```
GuestID      How old..?     Do you own...?    Why do...?    Why do...?    Why do...?
1            30             Yes               Convenience   To get...     So I can go...
```

Or, ideally, to pivot to this with the answers combined:

```
GuestID      How old..?     Do you own...?    Why do...?
1            30             Yes               Convenience, To get..., So I can...
```

The statement I'm currently working with is this:

```
declare @QuestionList as varchar(max)
select @QuestionList = 
    stuff(
    (
        select DISTINCT ',[' + RIGHT(Question,128) + ']'
        from AnnualSurveyAnswers
        where GuestId = 43
        for xml path ('')
        ),1,1,'')

declare @dynamic_PQ as varchar(max)
set @dynamic_PQ = 'select [GuestID], ' + @QuestionList + 
    'from
    (
        Select [GuestID],RIGHT([Question],128)AS Question,[Answer]
        From dbo.AnnualSurveyAnswers
    ) as S

    PIVOT

    (
        MAX([Answer])
        for Question IN (' + @QuestionList + ')
    ) as P
    '
Exec(@dynamic_PQ)
```

Results:

```
GuestID     How old...?     Do you own...?     Why do you...?
1           30              Yes                Convenience
2           35              Yes                To get the girl
```

I had to add `DISTINCT` to `@QuestionList` because I received an error about the column being specified multiple times. Makes sense. We can't have multiple columns with the same name. However, with `DISTINCT`, it now only displays one of the multiple choice answers. I also added `MAX` to cover the aggregate requirement over `[Answer]`, but maybe I should use something different?

There are multiple, multiple choice questions and they may contain 1 response or 8 responses. Are there any options other than altering the original data?

Comment: Oh, and in case anyone is wondering, I had to do `Right (Question,128)` because the column names have a character limit of 128 and most of my questions exceed that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few things that can be done to get the result.

If you want the data in the separate columns, then I would include `row_number()` and `count()` to split the questions with multiple answers into separate columns similar to this:

```
declare @QuestionList as varchar(max)
declare @dynamic_PQ as varchar(max)

select @QuestionList = 
    stuff(
    (
        select DISTINCT ', ' 
          + Quotename(Question
          + case when cnt = 1 then '' else +'_'+cast(rn as varchar(10)) end)
        from
        (
          select distinct guestid,
            RIGHT(Question,128) question,
            count(*) over(partition by question) cnt,
            row_number() over(partition by question, guestid order by question) rn
          from AnnualSurveyAnswers
        ) t1
        -- where GuestId = 1
        for xml path ('')
        ),1,1,'')

set @dynamic_PQ = 'select [GuestID], ' + @QuestionList + 
    'from
    (
        Select [GuestID],
          Question
          + case when cnt = 1 then '''' else +''_''+cast(rn as varchar(10)) end Question,
          [Answer]
        from
        (
          select guestid,
            RIGHT([Question],128) AS Question,
            answer,
            count(*) over(partition by question) cnt,
            row_number() over(partition by question, guestid order by question) rn
          from dbo.AnnualSurveyAnswers
        ) src
    ) as S

    PIVOT

    (
        MAX([Answer])
        for Question IN (' + @QuestionList + ')
    ) as P
    '

Exec(@dynamic_PQ)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/559f5/18).

This gives the result:

```
| GUESTID | DO YOU OWN A CAR?_1 | HOW OLD ARE YOU?_1 | WHY DO YOU OWN A CAR?_1 | WHY DO YOU OWN A CAR?_2 |            WHY DO YOU OWN A CAR?_3 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|       1 |                 Yes |                 30 |             Convenience |         To get the girl | So I can go through the drive-thru |
|       2 |                 Yes |                 38 |           Killing frogs |          To get the guy |     So I can go through the tunnel |
```

If you want the answers concatenated into a single column, then you can use:

```
declare @QuestionList as varchar(max)
declare @dynamic_PQ as varchar(max)

select @QuestionList = 
    stuff(
    (
        select DISTINCT ', ' 
          + Quotename(Question)
        from
        (
          select guestid,
            RIGHT(Question,128) question
          from AnnualSurveyAnswers
        ) t
        where GuestId = 1
        for xml path ('')
        ),1,1,'')

set @dynamic_PQ = 'select [GuestID], ' + @QuestionList + 
    ' from
    (
        Select [GuestID],
          Question,
          STUFF((SELECT distinct '', '' + a2.answer
                   from AnnualSurveyAnswers a2
                   where src.guestid = a2.guestid
                      and src.question = RIGHT(a2.Question,128)
                      FOR XML PATH(''''), TYPE
                      ).value(''.'', ''NVARCHAR(MAX)'') 
                  ,1,1,'''') answer
        from
        (
          select guestid,
            RIGHT([Question],128) AS Question,
            answer
          from dbo.AnnualSurveyAnswers 
        ) src
    ) as S
    PIVOT

    (
        MAX([Answer])
        for Question IN (' + @QuestionList + ')
    ) as P
    '

Exec(@dynamic_PQ)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1f2d1e/34). This gives the result:

```
| GUESTID | DO YOU OWN A CAR? | HOW OLD ARE YOU? |                                             WHY DO YOU OWN A CAR? |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|       1 |               Yes |               30 |  Convenience, So I can go through the drive-thru, To get the girl |
```

Comment: Bluefeet, I was hoping I'd hear from you. You have a ton of great SQL answers out there. I ran this, but the results came back with the first ID with the values, but the rest of the ID's yielded NULL. So in the case of the above example, GuestID 1 gives a full row of answers, but GuestID 2 - 300 gives all NULL values. My original where statement in `@QuestionList` has GuestID = 43 because that's the first GuestID value in my table, FYI.

Comment: @BobbyScon Can you update the SQL Fiddle with some more data for the table?  It is difficult when the sample you provided has only one `guestid`.

Comment: That looks great in the Fiddle. I've gone home for the day, but I will run this against my real data tomorrow and see if it all plays out. I also tried removing 1 of the multiple choice answers from GuestID 2 and it worked out well. I'm sure I'll find another glitch with live data, but this is an awesome place for me to work from.

Comment: Your brain scares me a little. I wish I could +1 a few more times! Tested against the live data, it appears to do exactly what I want. Thank you!

Comment: @BobbyScon I am glad it is working for you on your live data. :)